# Breakpoint within Vue instance method after npm build

Tags: javascript, debugging, npm, vue.js, breakpoints

I am new to Vue.js, and I am loving it. Previously I used JQuery and having to do everything manually was very inefficient. I liked, however, having the code I wrote in the Chrome debugger so that I could add breakpoints and see what was happening anywhere in my application.

Now I moved to Vue.js, and I am using `vue-cli` and `npm` to create, and build a Vue application that generates the actual app code under `dist/build.js`. I have a method within one Vue component which is not showing any error, but is not behaving as expected.

Is it possible to add a breakpoint within *that* method so that I see what it is receiving and how it is handling it, running it step-by-step?

From what I have seen, the source code I wrote in the Vue component is within `build.js`, inside a loooong string within an eval function.

Comment: Add `debugger` at the beginning of your method?

Comment: thanks! that was easy! Would like to add the answer?

Comment: btw is that a vue functionality or an npm one?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal

Comment: Sure, I'll cover all these details in the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug your js applications you can add a `debugger` statement, it adds breakpoints to your code where applied.

> The debugger statement invokes any available debugging functionality, such as setting a breakpoint. If no debugging functionality is available, this statement has no effect.
>
> [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)

It is a javascript feature, which got it's initial definition in [ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.15)